# Building XML in Perl with Tab Delimited File

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2, csv

I am relative new to Perl. Please check to see what I am doing wrong.

I have following input tab delimited file, which need to be built to XML, 'pin'number is the unique identifier. If the 'Pin' matches then
populate and show multiple 'CHARGE' under the report.

```
Reason1 Reason2 Reason3 Pin Name    Zip Date    Time

data1   data2   data3   Pin 1   data5   data6   data7   data8
data1   data2   data3   Pin 1   data5   data6   data9   data10
data1   data2   data3   Pin 1   data5   data6   data11  data12
```

I want it to build following XML

```
<XML_FILE>
  <REPORT TYPE="AB">
    <REASON1>data1</REASON>
    <REASON2>data2</REASON2>
    <REASON3>data3</REASON3>
    <PERSON>
      <PIN>Pin 1</PIN>
      <NAME>data5</NAME>
      <ZIP>data6<ZIP>
    </PERSON>
    <CHARGE>
      <DATE>data7</DATE>
      <TIME>data8</TIME>
    </CHARGE>
    <CHARGE>
       <DATE>data9</DATE>
       <TIME>data10<TIME>
    </CHARGE>
    <CHARGE>
       <DATE>data11</DATE>
       <TIME>data12</TIME>
    </CHARGE>
  </REPORT>
</XML_FILE>


use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $READFILENAME = "SomeDir\\data.txt";
my $WRITEFILENAME = "SomeDir\\test.xml";

my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0');
my $root = $doc->createElement("XML_FILE");
open (FILEWRITE, ">$WRITEFILENAME");
open (READFILE, $READFILENAME);
my $copy_person_pin = "XX";
foreach (<READFILE>) {
    my $line = $_; chomp $line;
    my @data = split(/\t/,$line);
    my $reason1 = $data[0];
    my $reason2 = $data[1];
    my $reason3 = $data[2];
    my $person_pin = $data[3];
    my $name = $data[4];
    my $zip = $data[5];
    my $date = $data[6];
    my $time = $data[7];
    my $report = $doc->createElement("REPORT");
    if ($person_pin ne $copy_person_pin)
    {  
      # Build the Report tags
      # I had to put $report out of if loop so that $report is avalible in else statement
      # my $report = $doc->createElement("REPORT");
      $report->setAttribute('TYPE'=>'AB');
      my @sortedReportTag = qw ( REASON1
                REASON2
                REASON3
                ); 

      my %reportHashTags;
      @reportHashTags { @sortedReportTag } = ($reason1,
                     $reason2,
                     $reason3
                         );                                                                            
      buildXMLElements(\@sortedReportTag, \%reportHashTags, $report); 

      $root-> appendChild($report);

      # Build the element for Person Tag
      my $person = $doc->createElement("PERSON");
      my @sortedPersonTag = qw ( PIN
                NAME
                ZIP); 
      my %personHashTags;
      @personHashTags { @sortedPersonTag } = ($person_pin,
                     $name,
                     $zip
                         );
      # Build the elements for Person Tag                                        
      buildXMLElements(\@sortedPersonTag, \%personHashTags, $person);
      $report-> appendChild($person); 


      # Build the elements for Charge Tag
      my $charge = $doc->createElement("CHARGE");     
      my @sortedChargeTag = qw ( DATE
                TIME
                );
      my %chargeHashTags;
      @chargeHashTags { @sortedChargeTag } = ($date,
                     $time
                      );  
      # Build the elements for Charge Tag                                     
      buildXMLElements(\@sortedChargeTag, \%chargeHashTags, $charge);
      $report-> appendChild($charge);
      $copy_person_pin = $person_pin;
    }
    else {
      my $charge = $doc->createElement("CHARGE");     
      my @sortedChargeTag = qw ( DATE
                TIME
                );
      my %chargeHashTags;
      @chargeHashTags { @sortedChargeTag } = ($date,
                     $time
                      );  
      # Build the elements for Charge Tag                                     
      buildXMLElements(\@sortedChargeTag, \%chargeHashTags, $charge);
      $report-> appendChild($charge); 
    }
}

$doc->setDocumentElement($root);

# Write the XML to a file
print FILEWRITE ($doc->toString());
close FILEWRITE;

sub buildXMLElements() {
  my($elementTags, $hashTags, $parentElement) = @_;
  for my $name (@$elementTags) {
    my $reportTag = $doc->createElement($name);
    my $reportValue = $hashTags->{$name};
    $reportTag->appendTextNode($reportValue);
    $parentElement->appendChild($reportTag);
  }
}
```

The output I get is, basically only the first 'CHARGE' is showing up not the other two.

```
<XML_FILE>
 <REPORT TYPE="AB">
   <REASON1>data1</REASON>
   <REASON2>data2</REASON2>
   <REASON3>data3</REASON3>
   <PERSON>
    <PIN>Pin 1</PIN>
    <NAME>data5</NAME>
    <ZIP>data6<ZIP>
   </PERSON>
   <CHARGE>
    <DATE>data7</DATE>
    <TIME>data8</TIME>
   </CHARGE>
  </REPORT>
   </XML_FILE>
```

@stevenl thanks the reply. But it doesn't work. if I declared empty $report at the beginning as suggested then the script runs but it doesen't still add the second and third charge. It still has the same output as above.

Comment: I added the full code that worked for me

Comment: Great! Thank you Stevenl it woks. Thank your for all you effort...I voted for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

- The problem is that in your `else` block`$report` is a newly created
  element that has not been added to `$root`.
- What you should be doing
  is to reuse the existing `$report` element rather than creating a new
  one.

So I have would modify your code as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $READFILENAME = "data.txt";
my $WRITEFILENAME = "test.xml";

my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0');
my $root = $doc->createElement("XML_FILE");
open my $FILEWRITE, '>', $WRITEFILENAME;
open my $READFILE, '<', $READFILENAME;
my $copy_person_pin = "XX";
my $report;
while (my $line = <$READFILE>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @data = split(/\s+/,$line);
    my $reason1 = $data[0];
    my $reason2 = $data[1];
    my $reason3 = $data[2];
    my $person_pin = $data[3];
    my $name = $data[4];
    my $zip = $data[5];
    my $date = $data[6];
    my $time = $data[7];

    if ($person_pin ne $copy_person_pin)
    {  
        $report = $doc->createElement("REPORT");
        # Build the Report tags
        # I had to put $report out of if loop so that $report is avalible in else statement
        # my $report = $doc->createElement("REPORT");
        $report->setAttribute('TYPE'=>'AB');
        my @sortedReportTag = qw ( REASON1
                  REASON2
                  REASON3
                  ); 

        my %reportHashTags;
        @reportHashTags { @sortedReportTag } = ($reason1,
                       $reason2,
                       $reason3
                           );                                                                            
        buildXMLElements(\@sortedReportTag, \%reportHashTags, $report); 

        $root-> appendChild($report);

        # Build the element for Person Tag
        my $person = $doc->createElement("PERSON");
        my @sortedPersonTag = qw ( PIN
                  NAME
                  ZIP); 
        my %personHashTags;
        @personHashTags { @sortedPersonTag } = ($person_pin,
                       $name,
                       $zip
                           );
        # Build the elements for Person Tag                                        
        buildXMLElements(\@sortedPersonTag, \%personHashTags, $person);
        $report-> appendChild($person); 


        # Build the elements for Charge Tag
        my $charge = $doc->createElement("CHARGE");     
        my @sortedChargeTag = qw ( DATE
                  TIME
                  );
        my %chargeHashTags;
        @chargeHashTags { @sortedChargeTag } = ($date,
                       $time
                        );  
        # Build the elements for Charge Tag                                     
        buildXMLElements(\@sortedChargeTag, \%chargeHashTags, $charge);
        $report-> appendChild($charge);
        $copy_person_pin = $person_pin;
    }
    else {
        my $charge = $doc->createElement("CHARGE");     
        my @sortedChargeTag = qw ( DATE
                  TIME
                  );
        my %chargeHashTags;
        @chargeHashTags { @sortedChargeTag } = ($date,
                       $time
                        );  
        # Build the elements for Charge Tag                                     
        buildXMLElements(\@sortedChargeTag, \%chargeHashTags, $charge);
        $report-> appendChild($charge); 
    }
}

$doc->setDocumentElement($root);

# Write the XML to a file
print $FILEWRITE ($doc->toString());
close $FILEWRITE;

sub buildXMLElements {
  my($elementTags, $hashTags, $parentElement) = @_;
  for my $name (@$elementTags) {
    my $reportTag = $doc->createElement($name);
    my $reportValue = $hashTags->{$name};
    $reportTag->appendTextNode($reportValue);
    $parentElement->appendChild($reportTag);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to process the file line-by-line, don't slurp it. Read into the variable you are going to use. And, of course, use lexical filehandles. `while (my $line = <$READFILE>) { chomp $line; ... }`

Comment: Thanks! I will change the for loop to while loop

Comment: Another Perl tip: `use warnings`

Comment: And, remove the `()` from your subroutine declaration. These are not like other languages for specifying the arguments, but to "let you define subroutines that work like built-in functions".

Comment: Thanks! will incorporate those two suggestions.